Understanding a proof of Dominated Convergence Theorem for Bochner integrals using scalar version of DCT
I have one minor concern regarding the Proposition 1.18 in these ISEM lecture notes regarding the Dominated Convergence Theorem for the Bochner integral. The proposition is as follows:

Let $(A,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $E$ a Banach space. Suppose that $f_n:A\to E$ is a sequence of functions, each of which is $\mu$-Bochner integrable. Assume that there exists a function $f:A\to E$ and a $\mu$-Bochner integrable function $g:A\to\mathbb{K}$ such that
1.) $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n = f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere


2.) $||f_n||\leq |g|$ $\mu$-almost everywhere


Then $f$ is $\mu$-Bochner integrable and we have


$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A||f_n - f||d\mu = 0$$


In particular we have


$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Af_nd\mu = \int_A f d\mu$$

The given proof is as follows:

We have $||f_n - f||\leq 2|g|$ $\mu$-almost everywhere, and therefore the result follows from the scalar dominated convergence theorem.

My concern is that in the scalar dominated convergence theorem, it is assumed that $|f_n(x)|\leq |g(x)$ for all $n$ $\mu$-almost every $x$. Here, a priori we know that given any $\varepsilon > 0$, then for $\mu$-almost every $x\in A$ there exists $N_x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$||f_n(x) - f(x)|| < \varepsilon |g(x)|$$
and so, $\mu$-almost everywhere we have pointwise
$$||f(x)||\leq ||f(x) - f_n(x)|| + ||f_n(x)||\leq (1 + \varepsilon)|g(x)|$$
whence
$$||f(x) - f_n(x)||\leq (2 + \varepsilon)|g(x)|$$
I don't see how this gives uniformity, or an upper bound, for the indices $N_x$ so that scalar DCT could be applied. That is, I can't come up with a reasonable argument on why the following cannot be true: For every $M > 0$ there exists $S\subset A$ with $\mu(S) > 0$ and some (note possibly only one) $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$||f_n(x) - f(x)|| > M|g(x)|$$
That is, that we couldn't get a uniform constant for the bounding term $|g|$ to use scalar DCT. So how should the result be concluded?

You are mis-reading 2.) It says that $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ for all $n$ and for almost all $x$ [$\mu]$. This also implies that  $|f(x)| \leq g(x)$ for almost all $x$ [$\mu]$.

@geetha290krm I see, it's actually quite simple: $||f||\leq ||f_n|| + ||f - f_n||\leq |g| + ||f - f_n||\to |g|$, so just take supremum on both sides.
